# Magento 2 - Show template hints in backend

Tags: magento2, backend, admin-panel, magento2.3.4, template-hints

Is there a way to show template hints in the backend?

I need to add a new description field in catalog/product/edit and have to find out where the templates are located.

**UPDATE**: Just a hint, you don't need to fiddle with templates to add a new field. Just create a new attribute in **Stores -> Attribute: Product** and add it to the attribute set at **Stores -> Attribute: Attributeset**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is option in admin to show template hind for admin:

You can check at:

Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer

In `Debug` tab you will see `Enable Template Path Hints for Admin`

[image]